# How to show "Preface" chapter , "Notations" chapter and " contents" in the PDF bookmarks?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

How can I show  "Preface" chapter, "Notations" chapter and " Contents" in the PDF bookmarks but at the same time I dont want them to be mentioned in the table of contents?

Here is  a screenshot of my work:[image: bookmarks1]

[image: bookmarks2]

Thank you.

Comment: Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notations}` immediately after `\chapter*{Notations}` and similarly for all unnumbered chapters that you want to be mentioned in the table of contents.

Comment: @Bernard thank you it works but it will show the "notations" chapter in the table of contents which i dont want.

Comment: @Bernard I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

The `bookmark` package provides many useful macros for PDF bookmarks. Use `\pdfbookmark` to set bookmarks that should not appear in the TOC:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[chapter]{Preface}{preface}
\chapter*{Preface}

\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{BBB}
\chapter{CCC}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[chapter]{References}{ref}
\chapter*{References}

\end{document}
```

The third argument of `\pdfbookmark` is used to create an anchor (destination) in the PDF. In this case the anchors are:
`toc.section`, `preface.chapter`, `ref.chapter`. Anchors can be used to open the PDF at a specific position, similar to HTML anchor. E.g. if I enter `file:///home/andreas/test/t1.pdf#preface.chapter` in my browser, the PDF will be opened at Chapter Preface.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts. +1